# best way to handle static yet expandable lists

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

My database structure is something like this :

```
'Article'
 title
 text
 user_id
 language_id

 'User'
 id
 language_id

 'language'
 id
 language name
```

Is it good practice to manage such a language list using a mysql database?

I'm a designer, but as far as I understand, queering a database less is better. Since the languages will be more or less static, expanding gradually, yet be loaded several places on the site (user options, writing articles, changing site language etc) I'm thinking that my structure is terrible. I don't know how to pul it off or how it would replace my current list. I'm thinking JSON.

I'd like to get some sort of confirmation before I start rewriting everything.

Comment: *"queering a database"* - why do you want to change the sexuality of your poor database?

Comment: need some more info: can 1 user have more than 1 language? if that's the case our user table won't work, you need a user_language table with the id's of both tables.

Comment: I'm a big fan of a multicultural structure. Gays, arabs, whites, people who can't spell. It's all good. And yea, the user can have more languages, they have a many to many relationship going and a database in the middle with that info. But articles can have only one language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I can see is: What if a user writes in more than one language? If that is the case, you shouldn't be storing the language id in the user's table, simply because it would be much more simpler to query the Article table to find all of the languages that a user has written articles in:

```
'Article'
 id
 title
 text
 user_id
 language_id

 'User'
 id

 'Language'
 id
 language name
```

Comment: Users write articles in different languages, so far the site will be released in 5 languages and we will be using our users to translate the interface (using gettext and .mo files).

Comment: @rococopolkadotbandit What if a user can write in more than one language?

Comment: Good point, yea, slip up on my part probably caused by stress, haha. But yes, this is how my database is structured.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how big the list of translations will be. The fastest solution would be to store the languages in files, and include the right file based on the users selection.

Edit: I might have misunderstood this completely. My impression was that you are building a list of translations so that the user can choose to view the website in different languages. You need to clarify.

Comment: The user can view the website in more languages, but also select which languages they know and view the articles which they can read and understand, rather than just viewing the articles belonging to the interface language of choice. So if you're Dutch but know English, you can have the interface in Dutch but read articles in Dutch and English.